# How to get raw values with consul recursively over HTTP API

Tags: consul

Referring the below documentation of consul for HTTP API

> https://www.consul.io/api/kv.html
>
> recurse (bool: false) - Specifies if the lookup should be recursive
>   and key treated as a prefix instead of a literal match. This is
>   specified as part of the URL as a query parameter.
>
> raw (bool: false) - Specifies the response is just the raw value of
>   the key, without any encoding or metadata. This is specified as part
>   of the URL as a query parameter.

I was expecting decoded values in the response returned for below request
http://localhost:8500/v1/kv/?recurse=true&raw=true

The `recurse` option is working as I can see all the key/val pairs present in the response JSON but the **values are still encoded** (base64).

Is the `raw` query parameter not working or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: how would you know which key each value belongs to if you just get raw values?

Comment: @GalBen-Haim I think you misunderstood, I want the key-value pairs but the values should be plain decoded, as I am getting values encoded with base64

Comment: A consul kv value can be anything, including characters that break json. This is why values are base64-encoded and need to be decided by the client. (otherwise you could break the json validity for example by adding a comma to a value or similar).

Answer (score 8):

Their document is somehow misleading.
These parameters will work individually. However when you try to combine them, they don't work as what you think.

Some alternative way to address what you need.

You can do first get a list of keys by

http://localhost:8500/v1/kv/?keys

And then, looping through the key and get the value individually

http://localhost:8500/v1/kv/YourKey?raw

Otherwise, decode the value in your code.

Comment: I tried the first command which ends with `?keys` but it gives an empty array even though I have some values. When normal circumstances where I try to get a single vaue I pass a token at the end like this `curl -k -X GET https://consul.test.us-east-2.dev:8543/v1/kv/banuka-test/test?token=1995-8-18` Can you help me how to integrate this token and getting all the keys at once?

Comment: Can we add a string prefix in getting all keys??